# Как проверить, что индекс не выходит за границы массива, полученного из String.Split?

Tags: c#

У меня есть массив в который из файла помещаются данные и они бывают нескольких типов. Если точнее несколько видов разделения текстовых данных. И суть в том что может иногда в массиве во втором индексе может не быть данных, из за чего его нету и это вызывает ошибки. Через `try` и `catch` разумеется убрал ошибку но нету такой возможности как на php через empty проверить существует ли он?

Переменную разумеется за ранее создаю так `string[] app = new string[2];`

```
app = readText[i].Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
try 
{
    appRun(Convert.ToInt32(app[0]), Convert.ToInt32(app[1]));
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
    appRun(Convert.ToInt32(app[0]), Config.Instance.run_timer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы присваиваете

```
app = readText[i].Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

вы переписываете ваш `string[2]` новым значением, теперь у вас там массив произвольной длины. Длину массива можно опросить при помощи `Length`.

Итого:

```
string[] app = readText[i].Split(
    new char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', ';' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (app.Length > 1)
    appRun(Convert.ToInt32(app[0]), Convert.ToInt32(app[1]));
else
    appRun(Convert.ToInt32(app[0]), Config.Instance.run_timer);
```

Или проще:

```
var runTimer = app.Length > 1 ? Convert.ToInt32(app[1]) : Config.Instance.run_timer;
appRun(Convert.ToInt32(app[0]), runTimer);
```

Это значит, кстати, что инициализация `string[] app = new string[2];` напрасна: вы всё равно переписываете присвоенное значение.

Comment: условие через if (app.Length > 1) будет всегда проходить так как данные всегда есть но иногда на второй индекс нету текста
данные в виде 
486820:8000
251570
387840;9303
204300

Comment: @UlkyomeDevufol: Тогда используйте `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: возможно ли как то с этой опцией поставить условие чтобы если нету app[1] то в ней помещались данные ?

Comment: просто мне надо запустить мою функцию appRun(Convert.ToInt32(app[0]), Convert.ToInt32(app[1]));
и передать ей второй параметр и если я пишу app[1] также вызывается ошибка так как его не существует при некоторых обстоятельствах

Comment: Ну так заведите числовую переменную вместо app[1], зачем вам строка? Используйте `runTimer`, например.

Comment: простите тупанул ) решил проблему через Length